# Where can I get Drivers for a Maxtor One Touch Four Plus Hard Drive, to work with Windows 7 professional 64 bit?

Tags: windows, drivers, external-hard-drive

The Drive used to work (although intermittently it could not be found without multiple reboots). But then I installed ProTools Version 11 and now the computer can't find the Seagate at all. Windows is calling it an unknown device. When I click "Driver" it says "no driver needed" or something like that.  When I click "Update Driver" it says "The best driver is already installed".  I can't find a simple driver file anywhere on my computer, nor on the Seagate Web site.  thanks

Comment: You may need to just assign it a  drive letter (if it lets you) within Disk Management (right click on Computer -> Manage -> Storage -> Disk Management)

Comment: I don't know if it actually works, but as mentioned several times in [this](http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Other-External-products/Maxtor-One-Touch-4-Plus-Usb-device-not-recognized/m-p/8885) article you could just try replacing the USB cable :) It seems a lot of people with the same device are having trouble. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you gentlemen for your comments.  Would you believe it WAS the Cable!  I least expected that because I've coddled the cable and it was barely moved since getting it.  but I replaced it and the problem went away.  Thanks so much for taking the time to share your thoughts.